# Unreal Engine and Windows RT / Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, unreal-development-kit, windows-rt

I am new to game development and I found [here](http://www.unrealengine.com/en/platforms/) that Unreal Engine is available for Windows RT/Windows 8. I would like to make a very simple game for Windows 8(RT) but I see there is no support in UDK.

Is there a "magic button" to export a game created with UDK (let's say one of the demo projects) for Windows 8? Or how would someone create a Windows 8 game with Unreal Engine?

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully the link that you provided. Windows 8 RT is for full source Unreal Engine 3, which is available for game studios and quite pricy for a self developer to obtain. UDK, on the other hand, is available to self developers, no price for non-commercial software and some royalty fees for commercial projects but you will not have access to full source of Unreal Engine. You can publish your game using UDK for iOS, Mac OS and Windows PC as you can see. Publishing for Windows 8 RT is not available using UDK.